# Can't "see" KIE server in Drools Workbench using docker-compose

Tags: jboss, drools, docker-compose, kie-server

I'm running the [jboss/drools-workbench](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench/) and [jboss/kie-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server/) images with Docker using:

```
# Start Drools workbench
docker run -p 18080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-wb jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest

# Start the KIE server and link the workbench into it
docker run -d --name kie-server --link drools-wb:kie_wb jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
```

After this, I can access the Drools KIE server in the Drools workbench, like so:

[image]

I need to run these two containers using docker-compose. However, when converting the two `docker run` commands into docker-compose services, I can't "see" the Drools KIE in the Drools workbench.

Here's a screenshot of the Drools workbench with no KIE server

[image]

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  drools-wb:
    container_name: drools-wb
    image: jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
      - 18080:8080

  kie-server:
    container_name: kie-server
    image: jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
    links:
      - drools-wb:kie_wb
```

Notes:

Here's the output of `docker-compose ps`

```
   Name             Command          State                             Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
drools-wb    ./start_drools-wb.sh    Up      0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp, 9990/tcp
kie-server   ./start_kie-server.sh   Up      8080/tcp, 9990/tcp
```

And here's the output of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                       NAMES
2b94187cdfb6        jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest         "./start_kie-server.s"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 seconds               8080/tcp, 9990/tcp                                          kie-server
524be42c584c        jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest   "./start_drools-wb.sh"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds               0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp, 9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp   drools-wb
```

*My question is: How can I run the jboss/drools-workbench-showcase and jboss/kie-server-showcase images via docker-compose (and see the KIE server in the Drools Workbench)?* Is there some concept I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

User "jauffrey" commented on [Issue 21 in jboss-dockerfiles](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/drools/issues/21):

> I managed to make those work on v 2+ of compose files. I just compared
>   the container created with the docker run and the one created with
>   compose (using version 3.2), and I figured out this:
>
> ```
> 39c39
> <             "NetworkMode": "default",
> ---
> >             "NetworkMode": "bridge",
> ```

So, a workaround is to add [`network_mode: default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network_mode) in your services.